# Online Leaderboard with LootLocker SDK

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

i'm creating a mobile game, and i would like to add a global leaderboard. I followed the LootLocker's channel tutorial, but unity gives me an error. Can you please help me? These are the scripts:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using LootLocker.Requests;

public class leaderboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    int leaderboardID = 5655;

    public IEnumerator SubmitScoreRoutine(int scoreToUpload)
    {
        bool done = false;
        string playerID = PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerID");
        LootLockerSDKManager.SubmitScore(playerID, scoreToUpload, leaderboardID, (response) =>
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                Debug.Log("Successfully uploaded score");
                done = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Failed" + response.Error);
                done = true;
            }
        });
        yield return new WaitWhile(() => done == false);
    }
}
```

```
using TMPro;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using LootLocker.Requests;


public class gameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float time;
    public TextMeshProUGUI timeTxt;
    leaderboard leaderboard;
    playerManager playerManager;
    int prova;
    private void Awake()
    {
        playerManager = FindObjectOfType<playerManager>();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        time = 60f;
        StartCoroutine(LoginRoutine());
    }
    void Update()
    {
        time -= Time.deltaTime;
        timeTxt.text = Mathf.Round(time).ToString();
        timeFinished();
        

    }

    IEnumerator LoginRoutine()
    {
        bool done = false;
        LootLockerSDKManager.StartGuestSession((response) =>
        {
            if (response.success)
            {
                Debug.Log("Player was logged in");
                PlayerPrefs.SetString("PlayerID", response.player_id.ToString());
                done = true;

            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Couldnt start session");
                done = true;
            }

        });

        yield return new WaitWhile(() => done == false);
    }

     public IEnumerator restartGame()
    {
       
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
            yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(1f);
            yield return leaderboard.SubmitScoreRoutine(playerManager.highscore);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        
    }

    void timeFinished()
    {
        if (time <= 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(restartGame());
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:
*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
gameManager+d__9.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/gameManager.cs:62)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at :0)*

I don't really know what's happening, so i would be really glad if someone could help me!

Answer (score 1):

Creator of the tutorial here!
It looks like you have a missing reference to leaderboard.
In the Unity Editor, you need to drag a reference to the leaderboard-script that you have from the gameManager.
Hope that this fixes your issue!